# UITableView accessoryView position was strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The UITableView accessaoryView of my app work fine on below iOS 9.0, It's like this [image]

The same project run on iOS 9.0, It's like this[image]

There have a offset, the detail code about accessoryView like this:

```
    CGRect abc = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width/2,    supportMininumHeight);
    UIView *customView = [self addControlFromArrayToAccessory :controlContent:indexPath:abc];
    cell.accessoryView =  customView;
    cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Please give some advice, Thx.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way to do this is make your custom cell in Interface builder with Auto layout, and load that cell in your tableView. I don't think custom accessory view is the right choose to do in your case.

Comment: It's not easy way,  My proj always use code to build UI,for me ,it's a big thing. :)  Thx for your advice